# Laravel trying to do hasOneThrough or similar

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I can see in Laravel docs they have `hasManyThrough`, which is great, but my end model needs a `hasONE` , not many , do I just use `hasManyThrough` and live with it or is there a similar function or workaround ?

I noticed that there is a request for it on github dating back to 2015 so clearly it hasn't made it as yet.

In short, I have `member`, which hasMany `sessions` and then I have various models underneath `sessions`, which I would like to access the `member` using `hasOneThrough`, eg , `post` -> `hasOneThrough` -> `session` = `member`.

Thanks

Comment: Make it more clear, please. Why don't you use smth direct like `user_id` for member?

Comment: well I feel its overkill that every model/table like `post` has both `session_id` and `member_id`; so I want to use `session_id` and then be able to find the member through the session.  I will try add more detail soon.

Comment: What I'm trying to understand is why you have sessions as entities.

Comment: don't think of it as what you would expect from a php session, its an internal thing